# Putting logarithmic scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code where I draw some arrows depending on the value of the variable, but sometimes those values are big like 9000 and sometimes the values are smaller for example 400. So how can I do the scales of the chart in logarithmic just to the axes scale change depending of the value of the arrows.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations, cycle
from numpy import sin, cos
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Circle, PathPatch
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
import wave
import sys
import matplotlib as mpl


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("auto")
ax.set_autoscale_on(True)

font = {'family' : 'broadway',
        'color'  : 'blue',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 16,
        'horizontalalignment': 'right',
        }

#dibujar cubo
r = [-10000, 10000]
for s, e in combinations(np.array(list(product(r,r,r))), 2):
    if np.sum(np.abs(s-e)) == r[1]-r[0]:
        ax.plot3D(*zip(s,e), color="b")

#dibujar punto
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0],color="g",s=100)

#dibujar vector
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)
#print "ingrese coordenada inicial: "

a1 = 120
b1 = -410
c1 = 200
d1 = -652
e1 = 800
f1 = -500

a1=0.3
b1=-1
c1=0.5
d1=-0.6
e1=0.2
f1=-0.4

a = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,a1],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k")
b = Arrow3D([0,b1],[0,0],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="r")
c = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,c1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="b")
d = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,0],[0,d1], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="g")
e = Arrow3D([0,e1],[0,0],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="c")
f = Arrow3D([0,0],[0,f1],[0,0], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="m")

ax.add_artist(a)
ax.add_artist(b)
ax.add_artist(c)
ax.add_artist(d)
ax.add_artist(e)
ax.add_artist(f)

ax.set_xlabel("Amplitud en X", size  = 18, color = 'r', family =  'verdana')
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitud en Y", size  = 18, color = 'r', family =  'verdana')
ax.set_zlabel("Amplitud en Z", size  = 18, color = 'r', family =  'verdana')
ax.text2D(0.05, 0.95, "Intensimetro de Audio", fontsize=16, transform=ax.transAxes)
#plt.title('Intensimetro de Audio',fontdict=font)

lista = [a1,f1]
list.sort(lista, key=abs, reverse=True)
print lista

lista1 = [b1,e1]
list.sort(lista1, key=abs, reverse=True)
print lista1

lista2 = [c1,d1]
list.sort(lista2, key=abs, reverse=True)
print lista2

if abs(b1)>abs(e1):
    h=b1
else:
    h=e1
if abs(a1)>abs(f1):
    j=a1
else:
    j=f1
if abs(c1)>abs(d1):
    k=c1
else:
    k=d1

a = [0, 0, 0]
b = [h, j, k]
xs,ys,zs = zip(a,b)
print (xs,ys,zs)

res = Arrow3D(xs, ys, zs, mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="simple", color='y')
ax.add_artist(res)

plt.show()
```

I put all the code just for you to identify where I have to change the scale to make it log.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use Axis method [`set_xscale`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale) or [`set_yscale`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale).

```
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but it gives me an error: 'MaskError: Cannot convert masked element to a Python int.'. And there is a thing, when I define the cube, I put the dimensions knowing the values of the highest arrow, so I'm in a trouble! How I can do this flexible?

Comment: Have you thought about just applying `log10` to the values of the arrows? You would have to offset them to make them all positive, but the scale would still be log.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  This appears to be a bug from at least 2011 related to surface plotting with log-scaled axes.  The mailing list thread indicates there is no easy work-around aside from log-scaling the data and plotting them linearly.

https://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg22832.html